# Highlight rows in a html table with selected value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html table filled with data in a portlet (this is part of the code):

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach var="message" items="${messages}">
    <tr>
    <td class="time"><c:out value="${message.timestamp}" /></td>
    <td class="sender"><c:out value="${message.sender}" /></td>
    <td class="receiver"><c:out value="${message.receiver}" />
    </td>
    <td class="performative">
    <c:out value="${message.performative}" />       
    </td>
    <td class="message"><c:out value="${message.shorterVersion()}" /></td>
    <td class="conversationid"><c:out value="${message.conversationid}" /></td>

    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

I know I can highlight rows using javascript when the row (or column) has some specific id, but I am not sure if I can do the same using values.

What I would like to do, is to highlight all rows with same values in "conversationid" column. The idea is as follows:

```
<a href="#"onclick="highlight('${message.conversationid}');">click me</a>
```

-> highlight rows with this conversationid

I know I could assign each row an id when creating the table but some rows will have same id and I think that is violates the concept of id in HTML, right? Also, it would be much easier to make it work using values but I dont know hether such thing is possible in javascript...

Also - follow up question: I am using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) plugin on my table and the column "conversationid" is hidden - will it affect the desired functionality (I think not, because the html itself stays the same)?

Thanks for any tips!

EDIT: here is an example:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="message">message1</td>
  <td class="conversationid">123</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="message">message2</td>
  <td class="conversationid">456</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="message">message3</td>
  <td class="conversationid">123</td>
 </tr>
</table>

<a href="#"onclick="highlight('123');">click me</a>
```

-> highlights rows 1 and 3.

Hope it is clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
function highlight(value){
      $( ".conversationid" ).filter(function(){
        return $(this).html()==value;  //specify your html here
      }).css('color',"red" );  

 }
</script>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td class="message">message1</td>
      <td class="conversationid">123</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="message">message2</td>
      <td class="conversationid">456</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="message">message3</td>
      <td class="conversationid">123</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="#"onclick="highlight('123');">click me</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am obvously missing something but can you take a look on http://jsfiddle.net/Cjb3B/ ? Thanks!

Comment: jquery file is missing

Comment: Thanks thats it - just one last thing: This highlights only the value.. what if I want to highlight the whole row? (the column with id is normally hidden)

Comment: `function highlight(value){$( ".conversationid" ).filter(function(){return $(this).html()==value;}).css('background',"red" );  }`

Comment: use css property as per as your need

Comment: Yes, I know that I could change the css but I can still only use the cell with the id - not the row in which it is, since (this).html() returns only <td class="conversationid">123</td>

Comment: `function highlight(value){$( ".conversationid" ).filter(function(){return $(this).html()==value;}).parent().css('background',"red" );  }`

Comment: use the parent() function of jquery

Comment: Okey, I didnt realize I have to call parent() after the inner function... this sovles the problem - thanks"

Answer (score 0):

using your html structure:

```
function highlight(my_id) {
    $('.conversationid').each(function(){
        if ($(this).text() === my_id) {
            //do highlight here
            $(this).parents('tr').addClass('highlight');
        }
    })
}
```

or using html5 data attribute

```
<table>
    <tr data-convid="123">
        <td class="message">message1</td>
        <td class="conversationid">123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-convid="456">
        <td class="message">message2</td>
        <td class="conversationid">456</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-convid="123">
        <td class="message">message3</td>
        <td class="conversationid">123</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

js function

```
function highlight(my_id) {
    $('tr[data-convid="'+ my_id +'"]').each(function(){
        //do highlight here
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
    })
}
```