# parent() function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Recently - I posted on SO this question: [Highlight rows in a html table with selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091514/highlight-rows-in-a-html-table-with-selected-value)

I have a generated html table and a JS function that should highlight all rows with same value of a cell "coversationid"

Here is an example on Fiddle which works great: http://jsfiddle.net/sa4ED/

However, If I apply the same code to my code, it suddenly stops working and I cant seem to find out why...

HTML/JSP (short version):

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach var="message" items="${messages}">
        <tr>
        <td class="time"><c:out value="${message.timestamp}" /></td>
        <td class="sender"><c:out value="${message.sender}" /></td>
        <td class="receiver"><c:out value="${message.receiver}" />
        </td>
        <td class="message"><c:out value="${message.shorterVersion()}" /></td>
        <td class="conversationid"><c:out value="${message.conversationid}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

There are links somewhere else which trigger the highlight function:

```
<a href="#"onclick="highlight('${message.conversationid}');">highlight</a>
```

JS:

```
function highlight(value) { 
    $(".conversationid").filter(function() {
        return $(this).html() == value;
    }).parent().css('background', "red");
}
```

When I click this function, it does nothing.

I know that highlight function gets called and everything and if I delete the `parent()` part, it works and all the cells with my desired conversationid values get highlighted. However, I want the whole row to highlight. So it does work without `parent()` but not with it.

Why? It is obvious that `parent()` called on a `<td>` should return the parent which is `<tr>` in this case, right? What is wrong? Thanks you very for any help with debugging...

CSS (short version):

```
table.pretty tbody tr.odd td {
    background: #FFFEFE;
}

table.pretty tbody td {
    text-align: left;
    background: #E1E9FF;
}
```

Comment: I believe the problem comes from the styling, not the code. Maybe you have `background` rules on the `<td>` elements that are overriding anything you may set on the parent `<tr>`.

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle of your example/

Comment: That may be the reason... I will post here my CSS here - can you take a look at it? I thought that it works like this: the last triggered style gets applied, but it probably does not work like that...

Comment: @Smajl, style rule priorities are not the culprit here, element coverage is. Since a background is set for `<td>` elements, any background you set for the parent `<tr>` will be invisible because it lies below the `<td>` elements. You may have to set the background of all `<td>` elements in the row instead.

Comment: Thanks - thats is the reason - if you post is as na answer, i wil laccept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `td` background to transparent.

```
function highlight(value) { 
    $(".conversationid").filter(function() {
        return $(this).html() == value;
    }).css('background','transparent').parent().css('background', "red");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
 $(".conversationid").filter(function() {
        return $(this).html() == value;
    }).closest('tr').find('td').css('background', "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parent().find('td') instead of just parent().
You already declared the td background color in CSS which overrides the background color of the tr.

```
function highlight(value) { 
    $(".conversationid").filter(function() {
        return $(this).html() == value;
    }).parent().find('td').css('background', "red");
}
```